# kafka producer api error Exception in thread main kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, bigdata

```
ERROR Failed to send requests for topics xyz with correlation ids in [0,12] (kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler:97)
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:91)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at kafkaprod.HelloKafkaProducer.main(HelloKafkaProducer.java:26)
```

I am getting this error for all my producer api programs, I tried to resolve it but I am unable to find what is the problem.

Kindly help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any code that produced this error?

Comment: You will get this exception when Kafka server is not reachable from your producer machines. Make sure that port is opened for your producers and  your Kafka servers are reachable from producers.

Comment: broker is in aws and i opened the port on aws,I am able to ping it also. when i run the program on my local with kafka also on my local then everything is working... but when I tried to run progam  on my local to broker on aws I am getting this error